# Wrap multiline String for Junit Testing

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

To compare multiline text results in JUnit Tests I often need to go from a text representation
to Java code that initialize a string with the multiline text.

E.g. if the test should check for an xml string containing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Customer>
    <id>100</id>
    <name>John Doe</name>
    <orders>
        <Order>
            <address>100 main street, smalltown, pa</address>
            <orderid>1100</orderid>
        </Order>
        <Order>
            <address>5 broadway, ny, ny</address>
            <orderid>1200</orderid>
        </Order>
    </orders>
</Customer>
```

I'd like to use a tool/generator that takes the above input and get the following result:

```
String expected ="";
    expected+="<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>\n";
expected+="<Customer>\n";
expected+="    <id>100</id>\n";
expected+="    <name>John Doe</name>\n";
expected+="    <orders>\n";
expected+="        <Order>\n";
expected+="            <address>100 main street, smalltown, pa</address>\n";
expected+="            <orderid>1100</orderid>\n";
expected+="        </Order>\n";
expected+="        <Order>\n";
expected+="            <address>5 broadway, ny, ny</address>\n";
expected+="            <orderid>1200</orderid>\n";
expected+="        </Order>\n";
expected+="    </orders>\n";
expected+="</Customer>\n";
```

and/or

```
    // Create test file
    java.io.PrintWriter srcWriter = new java.io.PrintWriter(new java.io.FileOutputStream(testFile));
    srcWriter.println("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>\n");
    srcWriter.println("<Customer>\n");
    srcWriter.println("    <id>100</id>\n");
    srcWriter.println("    <name>John Doe</name>\n");
    srcWriter.println("    <orders>\n");
    srcWriter.println("        <Order>\n");
    srcWriter.println("            <address>100 main street, smalltown, pa</address>\n");
    srcWriter.println("            <orderid>1100</orderid>\n");
    srcWriter.println("        </Order>\n");
    srcWriter.println("        <Order>\n");
    srcWriter.println("            <address>5 broadway, ny, ny</address>\n");
    srcWriter.println("            <orderid>1200</orderid>\n");
    srcWriter.println("        </Order>\n");
    srcWriter.println("    </orders>\n");
    srcWriter.println("</Customer>\n");
    srcWriter.close();
    // PrintWriter never throws Exceptions, one must check the error state manually
    //
    if (srcWriter.checkError())
    {
        throw new IOException( "can not write " + testFile );
    }
```

**What would be a development tool / eclipse utility or plugin to achieve this?**

- take a multiline input text from a file (in the IDE or on command line)
- escape quotes and backslashes
- convert to Java code that initializes a string literal and/or will do the file creation in the java code without the need of an extra file resource
- output result to new files and/or console or directly into editor to be used at compile time

The output file (if any) should not be shipped with the compile result. In the file mode an equivalent for the input file should be recreated from the string literals in the java code.

Comment: What about the two solutions you have above do not work? It is unclear what is the problem, could you clarify?

Comment: I am looking for a tool that converts multiline text to code so that I do not have to do this manually over and over again.

Comment: If you have a String object as the input, you just write it to a file (the escaping is not needed). And if you read in a file that has quotes or other special characters, the "escaping" is again not needed. Escape characters are only needed when entering a string literal in Java code as `String xyz = "sfdsf"`, not when using a String instance.

Comment: What do you mean by "multi-line text to code"? I assume you are not trying to compile this string into Java byte-code.

Comment: I have modified the question a bit to clarify that I really want the string and file creation right in the java code and *not* in a separate resource.

Comment: May I ask why? Why not keeping the resource separate? Wouldn't it be even more maintainable? What is the added value?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you are copying the multi-line text from another source, and you are using Eclipse, it can automatically convert your text into a multiline String literal.

In my version, enable it under Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Typing -> Escape text when pasting into a String literal

Then if you type

```
String expected = "
```

and copy some text like

```
blah
blah
blah
blah
blah
```

and then paste your string, Eclipse creates:

```
 String expected = "blah\n" + 
 "blah\n" + 
 "blah\n" + 
 "blah\n" + 
 "blah"
```

Personally I think it would be nice if Java had a multi-line equivalent to Perl's HERE documents.

Comment: excellent - I'll have to upvote and accept tomorrow since my upvote quota is used up today

Comment: Saves a lot of frustration. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why not just store your XML in an separate file and read it in to a String using Apache Commons?

```
String fileName = "path/to/your/file";
String fileText = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File(fileName));
```

See this for FileUtils - https://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html

Comment: I do not want external files at compile time. At runtime they are o.k.

Comment: I'm not sure I see the distinction in your question, but if that is the case I recommend you consider editing the question to remove the bullet referring to 'take a multiline input text from a file'.

Comment: Incidentally - based on your edit I would still recommend this as a possible solution. The files themselves can be located within your source tree, the location need not be external to your project or somewhere else in the file system.  That simply comes down to how you wish to structure your project; I have seen conventions using a 'resource' package to store files and the like for unit testing, etc...

Answer (score 0):

To me this looks like a failure. Basically, you want to test against a pretty printed XML with OS-specific line breaks.

Can't you simple write some simple Visitor pattern crossing the resulting and the expected XMLs to verify everything is as expected? In this way you will also avoid problems with invalid expected and produced XML.

Also, imagine if the namespace declarations change in order or the attributes change in order: the XML is semantically equivalent but syntactically different. How should this be trated? Is it a failed test? In my view, it is a pass.

Comment: the xml was just an example. Any multiline string could be the input.

Comment: I think you may still encounter problems with the line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

For non-eclipse users the following script solution might be helpful:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#   Copyright (C) 2012 BITPlan GmbH (http://www.bitplan.com)
# 
#   Author: Wolfgang Fahl
#
#
#   Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
#   you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
#   You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
#   Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
#   distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
#   WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
#   See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
#   limitations under the License.


#
# wrap code for use in JUnit Test cases
#
wrapJUnit() {
  file=$1
  mode=$2
  echo "wrapping $file with mode $mode"
  cat $file | gawk -v mode="$mode" '

# check mode and add header if mode is file
BEGIN {
  if (mode=="file") {
        print " // Create test file"
        print " java.io.PrintWriter srcWriter = new java.io.PrintWriter(new java.io.FileOutputStream(testFile));"
    }   
}
# work on each line
{
    line=$0
    # replace a single \ with \\
    gsub("\\","\\\\",line)
    # replace a quote with \ quote
    gsub("\"","\\\"",line)
    # output the modified line
    if (mode=="file") {
        print " srcWriter.println(\"" line "\\n\");"
    } else {
        if (more++) {
            print " expected+=\"" line "\\n\";" 
        } else {
            print " expected =\"" line "\\n\";" 
        }   
    }   
}

END {
  if (mode=="file") {
        print " srcWriter.close();"
        print " // PrintWriter never throws Exceptions, one must check the error state manually"
        print " //"
        print " if (srcWriter.checkError())"
        print " {"
        print "     throw new IOException( \"can not write \" + testFile );"
        print " }   "
    }
}

' > $1.wrap
cat $1.wrap
}

#
#
# show usage
# 
usage() {
    echo "usage: wrapcode inputfile [simple]"
    echo "  will take the text and prepare it for JUnit usage as a string";
    exit 1
}

#
# check number of command line parameters
#
if [ $# -lt 1 ]
then
  usage
fi

file=$1

if [ $# -lt 2 ]
then
  wrapJUnit $file file
else
  wrapJUnit $file string
fi
```